# NSScrollView documentView cannot be scrolled

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsscrollview

Coming from an iOS background, I presumed that `NSScrollView` would work out of the box, and I presumed that `contentSize` would reflect the size of the `documentView` passed to it. This is not the case, if the `NSScrollView` is created programmatically.

First issue was: why does `contentSize` not update when a document view is passed in.

Second issue was: why can I not scroll the scroll view, despite the fact there was more content.

Comment: I haven't experienced this myself, but have you tried setting the documentView's frame again after you call setDocumentView: ?

Comment: I just tried and it's the same deal -- contentSize stays at 1024x150.

Comment: Does the documentView have content that is inaccessible by scrolling? Or is the contentSize appropriate for the amount of content currently in the view?

Comment: There's some content sticking "out" of the bottom ('canvas' class has "isFlipped" set; I tried removing that but it did not affect anything).

Comment: Another weirdness is, I get the bounce effect by dragging down (i.e. scroll view scrolls the thing down showing black above) which resets on release, but it doesn't bounce (or move at all) when I try to drag *up*.

Comment: I just tried making another scroll view in a clean place and it works, but its contentSize does not reflect the documentView frame, so I am totally off track it seems.

Comment: You are probably using AutoLayouts? Here is a quick article about using ScrollView with autolayouts, its for iOS but applies to OSX too. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: @Yas Kuraishi: Yes in fact, I am -- I am experimenting with disabling auto layout as I'm not sure how to translate the iOS specifics into Mac specs -- so far it's not making a difference, but I'll continue poking. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first question appears to be: don't look at `contentSize`, look instead at `[[scrollView contentView] documentRect]`.

The answer to the second is that you have to *explicitly* set `hasVerticalScroller` and/or `hasHorizontalScroller`. The scroll view will then dynamically create `NSScroller` views.

You can also use `setAutohidesScrollers:YES` to make those appear only when necessary.